# React Typescript OnClick with optional parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, callback, onclick

This has a simple work around, but I am a student and trying to learn typescript.  Thank you for the help.

I am trying to convert some custom hooks to typescript

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useToggle(defaultValue: Boolean = false) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);
  const toggleValue = (value?: boolean) => {
    setValue((currentValue) =>
      typeof value === 'boolean' ? value : !currentValue
    );
  };
  return [value, toggleValue] as const;
}
```

The type of ToggleValue is Boolean | undefined. I would like to use it as a onClick and just send the function for the default toggle.  This works when not using typescript.  I think it is because onClick can accept undefined but cannot accept the optional Boolean.

```
      <button onClick={toggleValue}>toggle</button> {/* MAKE ThIS WORK? */}
      <button onClick={() => toggleValue(true)}>set True</button>
      <button onClick={() => toggleValue(false)}>set False</button>
```

Using Typescript I am required to write it as a callback even when not providing parameters

```
<button onClick={()=>toggleValue()}>toggle</button>
```

Comment: `onClick` will pass the event as the first argument of the callback, and TS is warning you (correctly) that that's not the value your function is expecting

Comment: Thank you.  If the ToggleValue() accepts no parameters it works.  (without a set value functionality) Why would a function expecting nothing accept an event?  Would it make sense to add the optional event to ToggleValue, or is it a bad practice trying to make this implementation work.

Comment: just wrap it as you mentioned: `() => toggleValue()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you pass a function to the onClick event it will always pass the mouse event as the first argument and typescript knows it and is warning you that this event is missing when you use it as such.

You have two solutions to handle this issue, the first is the one your proposed:

```
<button onClick={()=>toggleValue()}>toggle</button>
```

When no argument is passed to toggleValue.

Otherwise you can add the click event to your toggleValue function:

```
  const toggleValue = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>, value?: boolean) => {
```

But when you need the value argument to your toggleValue you'll also have to pass the event as such:

```
  <button onClick={(e) => toggleValue(e, true)}>set True</button>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I added to the return tuple a function for 'on' and 'off' and gave toggle a single job with no arguments.  I thought I had it working with a useCallback but found effectively i was just adding a shell that changed the type from Boolean to Any